# How to return array from javascript call in java?

Tags: java, javascript, scripting

I have the following in a js file:

```
function serialize() {
return new Uint8Array(1024);
}
```

I invoke that function with the java scripting api like so:

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[]) ((Invocable)engine).invokeFunction(SERIALIZE_FUNC);
```

Which immediately throws the exception:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Uint8Array" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Uint8Array" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1)
```

I dont know much about javascript, but I thought this is how you define an array in JavaScript?

Comment: You define an array like this: `return [];`.

Comment: @tieTYT in javascript? then what is all this about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Comment: Hm, I have a feeling your JavaScript engine simply doesn't support it.  Which engine are you using?

Comment: @tieTYT The default engine, RhinoScriptEngine

Comment: What version of Java are you running?  It may be available in JDK 8.

Comment: Im trying with java 7 atm, 8 would be a problem though :/.

Comment: This may help? https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions But AFAIK, you can only use it in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Your run time doesn't support typed arrays by the looks of it. Try this instead:

```
function serialize() {
    return [];
}
```

or if it needs to be 1024 in length create an empty array of said length like so instead

```
function serialize() {
    return new Array(1024);
}
```